# Alamofire http request to local webserver

Tags: ios, express, alamofire

I'm developing an iPhone app and the plan is to send a JSON packet every so often from the app to a local webserver.  To do this, I had planned to use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). My POST method looks like this:

```
Alamofire.request(Alamofire.Method.POST, "http://XXX.XX.X.XX:3000/update", parameters: dictPoints, encoding: .JSON)
    .responseJSON {(request, response, JSON, error) in
    println(JSON)
}
```

The IP address is marked out, but I've made sure that this corresponds to the IPv4 wireless address of my local server.  The server is set to listen to port 3000.  The server configuration looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function (callback) {
  console.log("MongoDB connection is open.");
});

// Mongoose Schema definition
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var LocationSchema = new Schema({
    //some schema here
});

// Mongoose Model definition
var LocationsCollection = mongoose.model('locations', LocationSchema);

// URL management
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/update', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Got something from the phone!");
});

// Start the server
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port
  console.log('App listening at %s:%s',host, port)
})
```

So, this server seems to work ok.  I can test it in my browser and type the URL: http://127.0.0.1:3000 and it will feed me the index.html file.  If I type in http://127.0.0.1:3000/update... then I get the "Got something from the phone!" message.  However, when I run my app (making sure my phone is on the same wireless network as the server) and the Alamofire method gets called... the response I get is nil.  I also don't see the "Got something from the phone!" message.  Can anyone let me know why that would be happening... or better yet, how to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

A few thoughts:

1. You are creating a `POST` request in Alamofire, but you've told Express to handle `GET` requests for `/update`. Use `app.post(...)` if you want to handle it as a `POST`.
2. Your Alamofire code is looking for JSON response, but you don't appear to be creating a JSON response. In the short term, you could use `responseString` rather than `responseJSON`, but I presume you really want to change your web service to respond with JSON (to make it easier for the app to parse the responses).
3. Your Alamofire code sending a JSON request (but clearly when you send a request via the web browser, it's not JSON). Are you sure you wanted to send JSON request? (This is not to be confused with the JSON response issue.) Did you want to use the `.URL` encoding type parameter, rather than `.JSON`?
4. Whenever you have a request that works correctly from a web browser, but not from the app, it's useful to watch both using a tool like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) and you can then compare how they differ and diagnose the source of the different behavior.

Comment: Yes.  Ideally, I will send a proper response back to acknowlege that the package was process properly... But, shouldn't I see the console.log message that says it received something from the phone?  Right now, I'm just trying to see if a message that I send from the phone is even registered by the phone (after that I can parse up the message and send back a proper response).

Comment: I changed the Alamofire function to use `.responseString` rather than `.responseJSON` and the message that I get back is the following: `Optional("Cannot POST /update\n")`.  I also was using Charles when I did this, and I did not see any activity showing up in the log (however I did see a record when I entered the IP address into a webrowser on my computer).  Do you know what the Alamofire response means, or why it wouldn't be posting to that address?

Comment: @andyopayne Perhaps it's the `app.get` reference. Shouldn't that be `app.post` if you want to handle `POST` requests for the `/update`?

Comment: Well... that fixed the `"Cannot POST /update\n"` message... however, I still didn't get the `"Got Something From the Phone!"` message... and also, Charles doesn't seem to report any http activity when the phone is running and sending the JSON packets (I know this because I see the reponseString coming back).  The http request doesn't appear to ever make it to the webserver... but as I said... I can type in the address of the webserver in a browser (with the port) and it works just fine.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually... I don't think I changed anything in my server code (other than to change it to app.post) but it now seems to be working.  When the phone makes the Alamofire call, I can see the "Got something from the phone!" message in my console.  So, I think it's working now as it should.  Now, to move onto parsing the JSON message... but, thank you for your help.

Comment: BTW, regarding Charles, you have to start it before you start the simulator, and you have to run the app on the simulator for Charles to capture the activity.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running Express server and iOS Simulator on the same machine, try to use `http://0.0.0.0:<port>/<url>` instead of the actual IP, it helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the node server is not bound to the address you expect it to be. You should verify that when you type in the actual IP address in your "http://XXX.XX.X.XX:3000/update" in your web browser that it responds. Your question details suggest you've just been using the loopback address.

Comment: I have indeed confirmed that when I type in the actual IPv4 address with the port number that it does indeed serve up the proper page.  So, I've tried with both 127.0.0.1:300 as well as my IPv4 address:port and both methods work as expected.  In addition, I tried using the IPv4 address with port from a web browser on a different computer (the client and server are on different computers) and I can get the webserver to properly serve up the index.html.  So, it appears that this part is working properly, as far as I can tell.